# Integral of $\frac{1}{2-x^2}$

Tags: integration

I know that the integral of $\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \arcsin(x)$, but what is the integral of $\frac{1}{2-x^2}$? Is this how you do it?

$$\frac{1}{2-x^2} = \frac{1}{2(1-\frac{x^2}{2})} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \arcsin(x/\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Observe that

$$2-x^2=(\sqrt2-x)(\sqrt2+x)\implies\frac1{2-x^2}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2-x}+\frac1{\sqrt2+x}\right)\implies$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{2-x^2}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int\left(\frac1{x+\sqrt2}-\frac1{x-\sqrt2}\right)dx=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left|\frac{x+\sqrt2}{x-\sqrt2}\right|+C$$

Answer (score 0):

One of the antiderivative representations for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ is $\tanh^{-1}{x}+C$ where $|x|<1$.

Use the u-substitution $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$:

$$
\int\frac{1}{2-x^2}\,dx=
\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}\,dx=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dx=\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}\,du=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\tanh^{-1}{u}+C=\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\tanh^{-1}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+C.
$$

This is true only for:

$$
\bigg|\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg|<1\implies
-\sqrt{2}<x<\sqrt{2}.
$$

Comment: I believe it is true for any complex $x$.

Comment: Thank you. I edited it.

Comment: I mean, I think your answer is true, generally.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \sin^{-1} x + \textrm{ const.}$

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{1-x^2} = \tanh^{-1} x + \textrm{ const.}
\quad \left(\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{1-x^2} \ne \sin^{-1} x + \textrm{ const.}\right) $

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{2-x^2} = 
\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{dx}{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2} 
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \phantom{,}\tanh^{-1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} + \textrm{ const.}$

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. In fact, it doesn't even address it...And I didn't downvote (I almost never do)

Comment: Still editing.  About to "address" the question.  Firstly, the assumption is wrong!

Comment: I'm not sure what you say "is wrong": the OP is asking a question about whether something holds...then you tell the OP either yes or no depending, and explain. That's all. To just write two integrals doesn't really help, does it?

Comment: "I know that the integral of $\frac{1}{1-x^2} = arcsin(x)$, ..." does not make sense because $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} \ne arcsin(x)$

Comment: Good. Then tell the OP that, and correct him. To write just two integrals doesn't seems to be helpful, imo., in particular because none of your integrals is *exactly* of the same function as the OP's.

Comment: As explained above, was editing ...  You are just too fast!

Comment: You post, people react. You do **not** usually post, then continue editing and hope nobody pays attention to your answer until...who knows what. How is the public supposed to know you post your "answer" and continue editing it?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{1}{2-x^2}dx=-\int\frac{1}{x^2-2}dx=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int\left(\frac{1}{x-\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{x+\sqrt2}\right)dx = 
-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} \left(\ln|x-\sqrt2|-\ln|x+\sqrt2|\right)+C =
-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{x-\sqrt2}{x+\sqrt2}\right|+C
$$